# Arduino gsm receive SMS

Tags: arduino, gsm

I need to program arduino with GSM sim 900 to receive SMS and compare the received msg and phone number. 
Basically I want to read the message and phone number and store it in arduino uno.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use these AT commands:
AT + CMGF = 1:This command will convert the message style to text. In other words we are telling our shield that we are expecting a text message.

AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0 – This command will alert our GSM shield and now whenever it will receive message, it will automatically send an alert on the serial port.

you can refer this link for the exact program:http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2015/02/receive-sms-commands-using-sim900-arduino.html
Hope it is helpful.

Comment: I did the send and receive as instructed. 
Arduino prints received message. 
How do I compare the received message and do led on off or led pwm. 
For that I need to compare the message. 
Also I need to store the number of the incoming message. 
Kindly help

Comment: To compare strings you can use something like : if(sms_str==input_str)         To get string out of you received sms use indexOf(<some special char>)  and then use string.subString(a,b);//where a,b are the index of the sub string (your msg);  refer this :https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring

Comment: To Store the number of msgs received you can add a counter in the response() function and increment it every time you receive a sms

Comment: I will try this both.. Thanks a lot. Can you kindly help me with code though.

Comment: Received msg is of the kind. +cmt: phone number date and time

Comment: Followed by message

Comment: Does the message start from new line? If it starts from new line you can compare the input string directly with the message using if condition.

Comment: Yes the message starts with new line and it's basically a response from the gsm. I tried using serial. Readstring but did not get any valid response. It's reading char one by one serially in. Should I make an array and store the characters

Comment: Use Serial.readStringUntil('\n');  to get string till new line

Comment: I need to do serial. Read method for first at commands.. Am trying to use serial. ReadStringuntil but it doesn't work. Need help of string parsing the output is +cmt:  "phone number ", "date and time". Read on arduino forum they say it is not possible. Kindly help.